# run time error 1004 select method of range class failed

Tags: excel, vba

**I get the 1004 error when running the code:**

```
Public Sub UserSortInput()
    Dim userInput As String
    Dim promptMSG As String
        
    promptMSG = "Enter a numeric value to sort..." & vbCrLf & _
        "1 --- Sort by Division" & vbCrLf & _
        "2 --- Sort by Category" & vbCrLf & _
        "3 --- Sort by Total"
    
    userInput = InputBox(promptMSG)
    
    If userInput = "1" Then
        DivisionSort
    ElseIf userInput = "2" Then
        CategorySort
    ElseIf userInput = "3" Then
        TotalSort
    End If
    
End Sub
```

***If I debug it highlights:***

```
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A4"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

New to VBA so don't really know how to solve this. I have enabled the macro settings in Trust Center, still doesn't work.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that's the line it highlights? That line doesn't select anything.

Comment: Yes. It does it same for the other user inputs also. Thanks.

Comment: That makes no sense to me in the context of the error message. I suggest you post the rest of the code (for the three sorting routines) since there is no need to select anything to sort.

Comment: I have sorted it out, Rory. Thanks. It was just a problem of selecting something wrong in the VBA window.